# SQL Server - will PAGLOCK table hint cause high fragmentation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have an application where we are parsnig / loading large amounts of messages and loading them into a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.  We are using TVPs to pass collections which is enabling large throughput, however it is also causing us to encounter quite a few deadlocks.  We recently added the PAGLOCK hint to the areas where we were having issues and it has resolved a majority of the problems.

My concern is that this will cause a large amount of fragmentation? Is that correct? We are also working on some re-design options, but wanted to gain some isnight into the impacts of using the PAGLOCK hint.

Any suggestions / comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PAGLOCK does not affect fragmentation.  Fragmentation happens if the insert of a new row causes a page split because the new row does not fit in the correct page anymore and is therfore independent of the lock type used. Page splits are common if the clustered index key is not an increasing value like an identity. It also happens in nonclustered indexes for the same reason, albeit less frequent because more rows tend to fit in a page.

What that means is that you can't avoid fragmentation on tables with multiple indexes and a high insert frequency. Therefore you should reorganize/rebuild your indexes frequently, based on their actual fragmentation.

Answer (score 3):

`PAGLOCK` hint has nothing to do with fragmentation. Fragmentation is related to indexes on the table. Looks like you don't have the right indexes on the table for which there are heavy inserts.

`PAGLOCK` is a table hint which is related to concurrency. Please refer to SQL Server Books Online:

- [MSDN: Table Hints (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)